# $_ROW 'id' delete user with Get doesn't work

Tags: php

I have the following code to load users in a table: `register.php` here I want to delete users from. Only the second script `deleteUsers.php` doesn't work.

Can any body help me out?

register.php`

```
<?php               
    $edit = 'edit:';
    $account = 'Username:';
    $account = '<font size="4">'.$account.'</font>';
    $password1 = 'Password:';
    $password1 = '<font size="4">'.$password1.'</font>';
    $id = 'id:';
    $id = '<font size="4">'.$id.'</font>';
      //check db connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
       // Take everything from table and fill in $result
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       echo"<table border=4><tr><td>$account</td><td>$password1</td><td>$id</td><td>edit</td><td>delete</td></tr>";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // Take all data
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo"<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td>".$row['id']."</td><td><a href='/editUser.php'> edit </a> </td><td> <a href='/deleteUser.php'> delete</a> </td></tr>";

           }
            } else {
            // nothing in DB is 0 results
             echo "0 results";
             }
            echo"</table>";
             $conn->close();




                        ?>
```

You see there is an delete button who redirect to `deleteUser.php`
This is the page you find here below, unfortunately the delete function doesn't work:

```
<?php

require_once("/db_conn.php");

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id value
(isset($_GET['id'])

 // delete the entry
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM login WHERE id =$id")
 or die(mysql_error());


 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: register.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
echo "doesn'twork";
 }

?>
```

Comment: your link to `deleteUser.php` needs to have `?id=<the ID>` which in this case is from `$row['id']`

Comment: if you are using `$_GET` you must send paramters via link. like this: `deleteUser.php?id=$row['id']`

Comment: did you get the id in the delete page?? echo $_GET['id']; to  check it first

Comment: Ok, so `$_GET['id']` is not set or is not numeric. What is it then? That will give you a clue as to what is wrong. It would help to see how $_GET['id'] is being set. Also, `(isset($_GET['id'])` looks wrong; not only is it syntactically incorrect, but you already checked that in the condition of the `if` statement. At that point, that expression is guaranteed to evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the `id`

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                    echo"<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td>".$row['id']."</td><td><a href='/editUser.php'> edit </a> </td><td> <a href='/deleteUser.php?id=". $row['id']."'> delete</a> </td></tr>";

                            }
```

on `deleteuser.php`

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM login WHERE id =$id")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Dear Qaisar,
Your pice of code works great, but when I go to deleteUser.php I get this error:

Access denied for user 'kennislogin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: it is database connection error check you connection file and remove / if the files are in same directories.

Comment: I use <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db_conn.php"); ?> on every page. It's working in every page but not in this one. That's the wierd thing. Everything is in the same directories.

Comment: if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
use this statement for checking or connection that are using in register.php file

Comment: Okey, I am gonna try that. Tnx!

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error. Where should I put this if statement?

Comment: before the delete query.. checking the connection.. this is username of your localhost? kennislogin

Comment: what file you are including in register.php?

Comment: Where should I do that? for now the name is kennislogin indeed

Comment: Only my DB connection and my menu.php within a session. Both things I load in my userDelete.php. So I should have a session and a connection with the database.

Comment: echo "DELETE FROM login WHERE id =$id" before the delete query and try to run directly in database. check it it is working or not.

Comment: DELETE FROM login WHERE id =Access denied for user 'kennislogin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: you run the direct query? in database?

Comment: It's working now! Thanks for all the good help guys especially Qaisar!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the id variable :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo"<tr><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td>".$row['id']."</td><td><a href='/editUser.php'> edit </a> </td><td> <a href='/deleteUser.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'> delete</a> </td></tr>";
 }
```

Comment: why do you keep putting `<?php echo $row['id'];?>` back? you're inside of the string, you cant do `<?php` again

Comment: deleteUser.php?id=". $row['id']." use like this

Comment: that is what i did for my edit on your answer, yet you put the `<?php` back.

Comment: I get the ID in the URL, it seems to work. Unfortunately I get this error: "Access denied for user 'kennislogin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" what I do here, I include the following: <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/db_conn.php"); ?>. I use this on very page. It works on every page but not in this one. What's wrong here? Everything is in the same directory

Comment: check password for mysql

Comment: @Ramki, the password is correct. I use this include on different pages. There it all works just fine. This is the only page where it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

`$id=$_GET['id'];` must put after query